# Matched Filter BER vs SNR curve does not match the theoretical curve

Tags: matlab, signal-analysis, filter-design, signal-detection, matched-filter

I am creating a matched filter using **filter** command. The coefficients are also generated in another file using sigma delta modulator these are ternary coefficients **(+1,-1,0)**. I have generated 1 and 0 with equal probability, mapped the bits with a rectangular pulse then added noise and used filter command to filter the received signal with ternary coefficients. After retrieving of the bits when I try to calculate the bit error, the plot comes out to be flat, it does not resemble the theoretical curve and the error rate gives strange values. I'll really appreciate it if someone helps me, please.

The Pb values does not seem to be right. There is not much difference that is why the plot is flat

Comment: I find your code very difficult to understand. Please add more information about what you're doing, why you're using delta modulation, and what you're trying to achieve. Please consider posting a block diagram along (or instead of) your code.

Comment: @MBaz I wanted the coefficients to not just be binary but ternary. So to do that I used firpm and got the target coefficients to be made ternary. To oversample I used interpolation. The interpolated output is fed into sigma delta modulator which uses ternary quantizer. This code works fine as output (variable v which uses ternary quantizer) I get is +1, -1, 0.

Comment: @MBaz My actual problem is in the other code that when I plot Pe vs SNR, it does not show much difference which I have added now at the end of the question, please check it. I'll try to add block diagram as well.

Comment: We cannot run the code, at least the function TernaryQuantizer is missing. However, looking at your curve: You have 50% Bit error. This amounts to completely random output, which is independent of the input. I suggest you debug your problem first with infinite snr (i.e. noise=0). In this case, your receiver should create the correct output sequence. I suppose, it currently does not.

Comment: @MaximilianMatthé Thank you for your suggestion. and yes sorry I forgot to provide the ternary quantizer function. Should I remove the noise first?

Comment: just run your algorithm with n_var = [0]; and see what happens and where the problems occur.

Comment: Now the filter command gives me output in whole numbers '  Columns 9989 through 10000

    90    10   110   150    50   110   110    50   190    90   130   170'

Comment: and the received signal is same as that of variable x

Comment: @MaximilianMatthé I have added the function for Ternary Quantizer

Comment: @Abeer I still don't understand what you're trying to do. You filter a noisy sequence of bipolar rectangular pulses `r` with a sequence $a_i \in \lbrace -1, 0, 1\rbrace$. That is not matched filtering. What are you trying to achieve?

Comment: If you transmit a signal $Ap(t)+n(t)$, a filter matched to $p(t)$ provides an estimate of $A$ with the largest SNR among all possible filters. Can you explain your problem in this context?

Comment: @MBaz The purpose of this code is to create a single-bit ternary matched filter. To do this the coefficients of the filter should be ternary i,e (+1, -1, 0), the first code creates those and the input and output should be in single-bit format (binary). I should be able to provide the input and the matched filter detector should decide whether 1 is detector or 0 is detected

Comment: This is what I should achieve. You are right I am not able to determine the correct way of doing this. I am able to create ternary coefficients but unable to determine how to provide these to the filter and how to create a matched filter if the coefficients are ternary

Comment: "To do this the coefficients of the filter should be ternary" That is incorrect. The coefficients of the filter should be matched to the pulse shape. The ternary coefficients are your data, but the matched filter is matched to the pulse, not the data.

Comment: @MBaz I have added the block diagram with the question, please go through it

Comment: Then in your opinion what changes should I make in order to create the type of filter I mentioned. Please provide your suggestions on this

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I dont know, if this is exactly what you wanted to do, but here's a script that creates your theoretic curve. I used your mirrored coefficients as the transmit pulse, and the coefficients as the filter coefficients. This way, the pair becomes a matched filter pair.

```
N=10^4;        %No: of bits
 A=10;          %amplitude of S(t)
 T=length(v);          %duration of S(t)
 S=fliplr(v)*A;       %the transmit pulse
 E=norm(S)^2;         %S(t) Energy
 input = rand(1,N)>0.5;   % generating 0,1 with equal probability
 bits=(2*input-1);      %mapping the bits with S(t)
 x=kron(bits,S);

 SNR_db=0:0.25:10;
 n_var=(E/2)*10.^(-SNR_db/10);

 %Noise that gives SNR=0dB to SNR=7dB 

 for i = 1:length(n_var)

  n=randn(1,length(x))*sqrt(n_var(i));   %noise 
   r=x+n; %received signal

  %v=ternary coefficients, filtering the received signal and coefficients                            
   filtered=filter(v,1,r); 

   %sampling at T & using thresholding operation
   z=sign(filtered);
   z=(z(T:T:end)); 

  %recovering the sent bits
  received_bits=(z+1)/2; 

  %calculating the bit error
  Pb(i)=mean(abs((input)-(received_bits)));

 end

 %Plotting Pb Vs SNR     
  figure(1);
 SNR=10.^(SNR_db/10);
 P_theory=(0.5)*erfc(sqrt(2.*SNR)./sqrt(2));
 semilogy(SNR_db,Pb,'o',SNR_db,P_theory,'r-')
 title ('SNR Vs Probabolity of Error');
 xlabel ('SNR (dB)');
 ylabel ('Probability of Error');
 legend('practical curve','theoratical curve');
 grid on;
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you so much. The curve looks good. I have one question so I can understand the theory, I know the matched filter impulse response must be time reversed as that of input but why do you mirror the coefficients in this case?

Comment: The mirroring amounts to the time-reversal.

Comment: So in order to do matching the transmitted pulse now contains the mirrored ternary coefficients and then this pulse is matched with the matched filter which has those coefficients? In other words mirrored coefficients are being matched. Is my conclusion correct?

Comment: the matched-filter criterion is if, g[n] is the TX filter, then g[-n] should be the RX filter (or vice versa). This is what I have implemented.

Comment: ok I get it now. Thank you so much for the guidance, explanation and suggestions